# i am getting an error as "Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" in node js connected to mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, web, web-development-server

i was tring to create a signup form connecting react to the backend using node.js. it worked fine, but now i am facing problems as

> Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

when the username is correct (ie) results.length==0 is implemented, rather than inserting the data, it gives the error. when i inspect it:

> r.js:154 Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
> P

```
 const cors=require("cors");
    const { response } = require("express");
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const mysql=require("mysql");


    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.json());
    const db=mysql.createConnection({
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        password:"password",
        database:"ggsklogin",
    });

app.post("/checkusersk",(req,res)=>{
        const username=req.body.username;
        const password=req.body.password;
    db.query("select username from skcred where username=?;",[username],
    (err,results)=>{
        res.send(results);
        if(err){
            res.send({err});
        }
         if(results.length>0){
            res.send({message:"username exists"});
        }
        if(results.length==0){   
            res.send({message:"done"});
            db.query("insert into skcred(username,password) values(?,?)",[username,password],
            );

        }   
    });
    });
```

my front end code:

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ReactSearchBox from "react-search-box";
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { key } from 'localforage';
import { Alert } from 'bootstrap';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

function Newlogin() {
    const navigate=useNavigate()
    const[usernamea,setusername]=useState('')
    const[passworda,setpassword]=useState('')
    const[repeatpass,setreapeatpass]=useState('')
    const[loginstatus,setLoginstatus]=useState('')
    const check=()=>{
       
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/checkusersk', {
            
           username: usernamea,
           password: passworda,
        }).then((response)=>{
            
        if(response.data){
            console.log(response.data)
            setLoginstatus(response.data.message); 
            
         } 
        if(response.data=0) {
            navigate('/sk-details') 

         } 
        })
        
        }
        
    if(loginstatus=='done'){
            navigate('/sk-details') 
             }  
    const passwordcheck=(e)=>{
        if(passworda!=repeatpass){
            setLoginstatus("password mismatch")
        }
       
            check()
        }
    
     
    return ( 
        <div>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder='enter username' name='username' onChange={(e)=>{setusername(e.target.value)}}/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <input type="password" placeholder='enter password' name='password' onChange={(e)=>{setpassword(e.target.value)}}/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <input text="password" placeholder='repeat password' name='repeatpass' onChange={(e)=>{setreapeatpass(e.target.value)}}/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
    
            <button onClick={passwordcheck}></button>
        </div>

        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
             {loginstatus}
        
        </div>
        
      
        </div>
     );
    }  

export default Newlogin;
```

i am also expecting another solution from u guys. that is in front end, if the username is unique and passwords match, it should be redirected to "/sk-details". please provide me a solution for that too.

in the first case, i have tried to display the results, but it gives uncaught inpromise error.
in the second case it is not getting redirected when the username and passwords are ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is at line `res.send(results);` you are sending this response and when, as you said `results.length==0` is true it tries to send yet another response `res.send({message:"done"})` which is due to fail because you can't `.send` multiple responses from a single endpoint. If you need to send the `results` then you need another conditional logic for it, but if you didn't meant to send it instead remove it:

```
const cors=require("cors");
const { response } = require("express");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mysql=require("mysql");


app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
const db=mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password:"password",
    database:"ggsklogin",
});

app.post("/checkusersk",(req,res)=>{
    const username=req.body.username;
    const password=req.body.password;
db.query("select username from skcred where username=?;",[username],
(err,results)=>{
    // res.send(results); // this is removed so that below conditions can send response
    if(err){
        res.send({err});
    }
     if(results.length>0){
        res.send({message:"username exists"});
    }
    if(results.length==0){   
        res.send({message:"done"});
        db.query("insert into skcred(username,password) values(?,?)",[username,password],
        );

    }   
});
});
```

And not related to your backend error, the frontend's Axios is set up for failure with the line `if(response.data=0) {` you are assigning = a value instead of using comparison === operator, but even then you would be comparing an Object to `0` which would always be `false`, instead you would wanna check if the `response.data === 'done'`, to fix it:

```
// ...
const check=()=>{
       
    axios.post('http://localhost:3001/checkusersk', {
            
           username: usernamea,
           password: passworda,
        }).then((response)=>{
            
        if(response.data){
            console.log(response.data)
            setLoginstatus(response.data.message); 
            
         } 
        // if(response.data=0) { // This would always be false
        // Use this instead:
        if (response.data === 'done') {
            navigate('/sk-details') 

         } 
        })
        
        }
// ...
```

Comment: @DHARSHINIS can you create a new post where you explain the new issue thoroughly? You can tag me in here and share the link, I'll try to help there.

Comment: thanks for ur efffort, the backend issue is solved, but the front end issue is changed. it is  not navigating properly. once i get the username unique, i should be able to navigate, but it is not navigating rather it shows done. and then when i click submit again, it show username exist!! and "not navigating". so kindly edit the code or provide me with a code that does the job... thanks in advance :)

Comment: please tell ur username ... i am new to stackoverflow and i learning to tag...

Comment: @DHARSHINIS [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and create a new question and I will check it.

Comment: I have posted the question, pls check :)

Answer (score 1):

#### you can't send response more than once, your code should look something like this

```
 app.post("/checkusersk", (req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    const password = req.body.password;

    db.query("select username from skcred where username=?;", [username], (err, results) => {
            if (err) return res.send({ err });
    
            if (results.length > 0) return res.send({ message: "username exists" });
            
            if (results.length == 0) {
                db.query("insert into skcred(username,password) values(?,?)", [username, password]);
                return res.send({ message: "done" });
            }
            
            res.send(results);
        });
});
```